# How to implement/condense code

Tags: javascript, html

Here is basically what my code does when the image is click it will then maximize(animated)

```js
var image = document.getElementById('pic');

image.addEventListener('click', enlarge);

function enlarge() {
  var interval;
  var height = 100;
  
  interval = setInterval(function() {
    height += 7.9365;
    
    if(height >= 600) {
      height = 600;
      clearInterval(interval);
    }
    
    image.style.height = height + 'px';
  }, 16);
}
```

```css
#pic {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<img src='https://placehold.it/100x100' id='pic'>
```

But now i want to implement more img so when i click individual img and it will animate.

```
    $("img").click(function() {
    alert(this.id); // or alert($(this).attr('id'));

});
```

how do i place those function

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. Also see [ask], and check out the [help].

Comment: How do you place what? Neither your problem statement or question are specific enough

Comment: what do put in between `$("img").click(function() {
    alert(this.id); // or alert($(this).attr('id'));

});` so that when that "img" is clicked then the function enlarge() runs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you want something like this?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  
   $(".pic").click(function() {
     enlarge(this);
    });
    
   

 function enlarge(obj) {
    var interval;
    var height = 100;

    interval = setInterval(function() {
      height += 7.9365;

      if(height >= 600) {
        height = 600;
        clearInterval(interval);
      }

       $(obj).css("height",height);
    }, 16);
}
});
```

```css
.pic {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src='https://placehold.it/100x100' class='pic'>
<img src='https://placehold.it/100x100' class='pic'>
<img src='https://placehold.it/100x100' class='pic'>
```